# Automated XML data collection to display in a Google Sheet

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, google-apps-script, google-apps

I have been trying to make a Google Script that would display the most current river levels in a Google Sheet. 
I am looking at a XML document that is [here](https://water.weather.gov/ahps2/hydrograph_to_xml.php?gage=henn1&output=xml)

It's a very long document, but all I am trying to grab out of it is the observed river levels. 
Currently I have a google sheet set up that the river levels would collect all the data. I originally throught I got it to work using a `XMLhttprequest`, but found out google scripts does not support that function. So I have been trying to use a [UrlFetch service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/), but haven't had much luck yet.

The code I am working on looks like this:

```js
function Rivers() {
  var url = 'https://water.weather.gov/ahps2/hydrograph_to_xml.php?gage=llrw4&output=xml';

  var xml = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();

  var document = XmlService.parse(xml);

  var txt = "";
  path = "//site/observed/datum/primary"
  var nodes = xml.evaluate(path, xml, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
  var result = nodes.iterateNext();


  while (result) {
    txt += result.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    result = nodes.iterateNext();

  }
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  var cell = sheet.getRange('B:C');
}
```

When I try to run it I get the error `"Cannot find function evaluate"` I'm sure that has to do with the `fetchurl`, but can't seem to find a fix for it. 
Any help on the work around would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Apps Script runs on Google Servers. As a result, you don't have access to some DOM / BOM features or APIs available in your browser. This includes XPath for navigating xml documents. If you want to use Xpath, you will have to write your own functions for parsing it. Here's the example I found https://coderwall.com/p/cq63og/extract-data-from-xpath-via-google-apps-script

XmlService has its own methods for traversing xml documents that you can use instead of XPath. This is how you get all child nodes of the root element.

```
 var url = 'https://water.weather.gov/ahps2/hydrograph_to_xml.php?gage=llrw4&output=xml';

  var xml = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();


  var document = XmlService.parse(xml);
  var root = document.getRootElement();
  var children = root.getChildren();
```

You are getting the error because you are calling the function on a string variable.

```
  var xml = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var nodes = xml.evaluate(path, xml, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
```

The return type for UrlFetchApp.fetch() is HttpResponse. Calling getContentText() method of HttpResponse returns a string. More on this here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I think that makes more sense now. I went and added in something like var obs = root.getChild("forecast").getChild("datum").getChild("primary").getvalue();     That seems to spit out the number that I am looking for.

Comment: Glad I could help!